# Write to a file failes randomly

Tags: python, filepath

Im working on a app to check new anime episodes, but i have come across a wierd problem.
when writing to a file the write fails randomly at random spots at random times, yet at times it runs without a problem. i cant figure this one out guys.
Below is the problem part of code:

```python
def write_results(results, result_dir):
    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar()
    for i in bar(range(100)):
        time.sleep(0.02)
        list = results
        for line in list:
            file = result_dir
            with open(file, "w", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
                list.sort()
                for line in list:
                    file.write('' + line + '\n')

def main():
    call(["python", "anime_app.py"])
    file_dir = r"C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/ShowDownloader/filelist.txt"
    result_dir = r"C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/ShowDownloader/results.txt"
    read = read_file(file_dir)
    content = get_content(read)
    site = read_site(content)
    results = write_results(site, result_dir)
```

The error is always the same:

```
File "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/ShowDownloader/anime_web_app.py", line 15, in write_results
    with open(file, "w", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/ShowDownloader/results.txt'
```

example or it happening at "random" times:

```
97% (97 of 100) |####################### | Elapsed Time: 0:00:03 ETA:  0:00:00Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/ShowDownloader/anime_web_app.py", line 62, in <module>
main()
  File "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/ShowDownloader/anime_web_app.py", line 59, in main
    results = write_results(site, result_dir)
  File "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/ShowDownloader/anime_web_app.py", line 15, in write_results
with open(file, "w", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/ShowDownloader/results.txt'`
```

Comment: Generally, "Invalid Argument" means the path isn't valid. (Windows is a lot more restrictive about what constitutes a legal filename than most of your POSIX-y operating systems).

Comment: BTW, reusing the `file` variable name for both your filename and the file *object* is a bad idea. I'd strongly suggest a separate variable for each.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that Windows file locking semantics are picky -- you can't have the same file open for write more than once (even when other platforms would allow it). Though I suspect that would be a different variety of OSError, it's consistent with behavior being random / poorly-defined.

Comment: yes i fixed up the code a bit, there was a extra for loop in there aswell that i removed.

Comment: I dont know what happend, but its working consistently now. I cleaned up the code, remove extra for loop, added a properly working progressbar and its working now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this, `io` module is better for writing `UTF-8` files then `codecs` module that is mostly used for reading them:

```
import io

with io.open(file, "w", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    ...
```

Comment: tried it, still works and doesnt, so random error. It is wierd that it stops working mid writing at times.

Comment: Same error > with io.open(file, "w", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/ShowDownloader/results.txt'

Comment: i set a loop to run it a couple of times in a row and it did 2 writes succesfully then failed mid write: `100% (100 of 100) |#######################| Elapsed Time: 0:00:03 Time: 0:00:03
100% (100 of 100) |#######################| Elapsed Time: 0:00:03 Time: 0:00:03
 51% (51 of 100) |############            | Elapsed Time: 0:00:01 ETA:  0:00:01` and same error as previously

Comment: Well you can try using `//` instead of `/` as a last resort :)

Comment: tried, same thing. cant figure this one out, so wierd, ill reboot PC, mayby its just bugged somehow, the code should work

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what i did, but cleaned up the code a bit, removed extra for loop and fixed progressbar and the write is working perfectly now. fixed code below.

```
def write_results(results, result_dir):
try:
    pbar = ProgressBar()
    list = results
    write_file = result_dir
    with io.open(write_file, "w", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
        for line in pbar(list):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            list.sort()
            file.write('' + line + '\n')
except Exception:
    print("\n" + str(Exception))
    pass

def main():
loop = 0
while loop < 20:
    loop += 1
    call(["python", "anime_app.py"])
    file_dir = r"C://Users//username//PycharmProjects//ShowDownloader//filelist.txt"
    result_dir = r"C://Users//username//PycharmProjects//ShowDownloader//results.txt"
    read = read_file(file_dir)
    content = get_content(read)
    site = read_site(content)
    results = write_results(site, result_dir)
```